Died without repaying the money taken
My maternal aunts husband took some money from me promising to repay me somehow. He died without repaying. His son said he is not responsible for any such transaction. His father was a very pious practising brahmin and noble soul.
Question is how does karma affect the players here including me and my uncles son. I am more interested in present life and not future lives

Even if I have decided to let it go, what is the consequences for the son as father had promised to pay...
